# how to find the specific form control that has an error from FormArray?

Tags: angular

I am creating individual form controls like this and putting them in a form array, and looking at `statusChanges` on that...

```
<form>
  <input [formControl]="a" matInput />
  <input [formControl]="b" matInput />
</form>
<p class="error" *ngIf="errorMessage">{{ errorMessage }}</p>
```

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.a = new FormControl('', [Validators.required]);
    this.b = new FormControl('', [Validators.required]);

    this.array = new FormArray([this.a, this.b]);

    this.array.statusChanges.subscribe((status: FormControlStatus) => {
      if (status === 'invalid') {
        ...
      }
    });
  }
```

The first issue I am having is, the errors object on the form array is blank despite the controls having errors on them, so I am having to loop over the individual controls themselves which is inconvenient, but do-able..

The next issue is those individual controls do not have any information about which control they are, and I don't see any way to set a `name` property on a `FormControl` object-- so imagine I have more than two form controls in this object.. I need to be able to do something like:

```
const found = this.array.controls.find(control => control.errors.required);
if (found) {
  this.errorMessage = `${control.name} is required`;
}
```

But like I said, there is no `.name` so I am curious how does one accomplish this the "angular way" ?

Answer (score 1):

Meta: I’m on mobile, so I’ll need to come back to this once I can verify the assumptions and snippets I’m providing are valid.

Without checking, I’m relatively sure your example doesn’t work as expected. If you’re using a `FormArray`, the individual controls aren’t identifiable by property name/key, but rather by index. Also, I believe you need to bind a `FormGroup` to the `<form>` if your concern is following Angular semantics. The way I’ve seen this done is to set a `FormArray` on a `FormGroup` and loop over the controls dynamically.

In Angular 16 style:

```html
<form [formGroup]=“form”>
  <ng-container *ngFor=“let field of array.controls; let index = index”>
    <input type=“text” [formControlName]=“index”/>
    <p *ngIf=“!field.isValid”>A value is required.</p>
  </ng-container>
</form>
```

```js
readonly fb = inject(FormBuilder);
readonly form = this.fb.group({
  array: this.fb.array([]);
});

get array(): FormArray {
  return this.form.get(‘array’) as FormArray!;
}

ngOnInit(): void {
  const dataFromAPI = { requiredValueCount: 3 };

  for (let i = 0; i < dataFromAPI.requiredValueCount; i++) {
    const control = this.fb.control(‘’, [Validators.Required]);
    this.array.push(control);
  }
}
```

That said, as you can see from the snippet, this approach is generally for when you have an unknown number of fields of the same type. It breaks down when you try to label them because what you’re actually looking for at that point is a `FormGroup`.

Again in Angular 16 style:

```html
<form [formGroup]=“form”>
  <input id=“a” formControlName=“a”/>
  <label for=“a”>a</a>
  <p *ngIf=“!form.get(‘a’).isValid”>a is required.</a>
  <input id=“b” formControlName=“b”/>
  <label for=“b”>b</a>
  <p *ngIf=“!form.get(‘b’).isValid”>b is required.</a>
</form>
```

```js
readonly fb = inject(FormBuilder);
readonly form = this.fb.group({ });

ngOnInit(): void {
  const dataFromAPI = [
    { name: ‘a’, required: true },
    { name: ‘b’, required: true },
  ];

  dataFromAPI.forEach(item => {
    const control = this.fb.control(‘’, [Validators.Required]);
    this.form.addControl(item.name, control);
  });
}
```

You can also do this semi-dynamically:

```html
<form [formGroup]=“form”>
  <ng-container *ngFor=“let control of form.controls”>
    <input [id]=“control.label” [formControl]=“control”/>
    <label [for]=“control.label”>{{control.label}}</a>
    <p *ngIf=“!control.isValid”>{{control.label}} is required.</a>
  </ng-container>
</form>
```

As far as identifying which field is invalid, I usually see the approach above where responsibility for displaying a field-specific error message is delegated to the field. You should be able to get access to the list of invalid controls as you’re expecting if you’re using the `FormGroup` approach, but this is the more idiomatic approach from the documentation I’ve seen.

Comment: I see..  I still don't understand why FormArray or FormGroup has an errors object, which does not reflect the errors of its internal controls...